# Regex code to transform CSV in strings

Tags: java, regex, csv

I need to write a Java program that transform a CSV file into an array list.
A CSV line looks like this:

`5/3/2010,"Behrens, Michael Lakeside Apts","Lisle, IL 60532",PD: Noise or domestic reports for 3/25 to 4/28 for specific apt.,5/10/2010, 5/10/2010,1`

I need it like this:

```
DATE RECEIVED:5/3/2010  
NAME / COMPANY:Behrens, Michael Lakeside Apts  
CITY, STATE, ZIP:Lisle, IL 60532  
Department / Documents:PD: Noise or domestic reports for 3/25 to 4/28 for specific apt.   
Due Date 5 Days 10 Days:5/10/2010  
DATE COMPLETED:5/10/2010  
Hours Spent Fulfilling Request:1
```

So far I've got this: `,|[\"]` but I need to remove `,` from `""`

Answer (score 4):

What you need isn't regex, it's a [csv parser (openCSV)](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Alternatively you *could* do this manually using something like

```
String[] arr = string.split("(\\\",\\\"|(?<!\\\"),)");
String output = "DATE RECEIVED: " + arr[0] + 
                "\nZIP: " + ...
                "...  " + ...;
```

Comment: he has comma inside a quote so simple spliting does not work well. i doubt any csv parser could do this.

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay enough attention, changed it to some magic regex :)

Comment: The parentheses in your regex are mismatched - there's one more `)` than `(`.

Comment: The parser suggested by Johan (openCSV) can parse this correctly. It will work fine as long as commas only appear in quoted values.

Comment: Then the csv parser should be used.

Comment: Sorry Johan, this example doesn't compile - the second double-backslash is outside the string literal.

Comment: Thx again for pointing that out, I've already fixed it in my previous edit. Morning regex is after all morning regex :)